# How to show more than one item in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a list of students and each one with his respects courses; I have something like this:

```
function app() {
  const names = ["Mary", "Stuart"];
  const courses = ["Math", "Biology"]

  return (
    <div id="students">
      {names.map(aName =>
        (
          <Card>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography>aName</Typography>
            </Cardcontent>
          </Card>

          {courses.map(aCourse =>
            (
              <Card>
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography>aCourse</Typography>
                </Cardcontent>
              </Card>
            )
          )}
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

But react throws the error: ')' expected. ts(1005).
How can I solve that?

Comment: Please start by indenting your code. SO has an auto-formatter. Please use it! `function app(const ` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this.

```
function app() {
  const names = ["Mary", "Stuart"];
  const courses = ["Math", "Biology"];
  return (
    <div id="students">
      {names.map((aName) => (
        <Card>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography>{aName}</Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      ))}
      {courses.map((aCourse) => (
        <Card>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography>{aCourse}</Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

1. Use proper indentation.
2. Use some formatter for React code like Prettier. You can install one in Visual Studio Code (see Extensions) or other IDE. A formatter can format your code automatically.
3. Also when you see an error, usually it tells you what to do.

> error: ')' expected. ts(1005);

It means that you're missing ')' symbol somewhere in your code (error also gives you a line number).

Answer (score 0):

You will need [React fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) to fix your issue. Please always add key for the element inside loops:

```js
function app() {
  const names = ["Mary", "Stuart"];
  const courses = ["Math", "Biology"]

  return (
    <div id="students">
      {names.map(aName =>
        (
          <React.Fragment key={aName}>
            <Card>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography>aName</Typography>
              </Cardcontent>
            </Card>

            {courses.map(aCourse =>
              (
                <Card>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography>aCourse</Typography>
                  </Cardcontent>
                </Card>
              )
            )}
          </React.Fragment>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```